# Error al pasar datos de ajax a php (Notice: Undefined index: id)

Tags: php, ajax

Este es el código ajax: al clickear sobre un botón se abre esa función y guarda en una variable llamada id el id de ese botón. Luego se supone que con ajax se envía esa id a form.php pero me aparece el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: id

```
$("button").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
          url: 'form.php',
          method: "POST",
          data: {id : id},
          success: function() {
            $("#form").load("form.php");
          }
        });
      });
```

Aquí el código PHP de form.php

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}


$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;

 ?>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en la llamada Ajax. Mas específicamente al crear la llave o key id.

Debes reemplazar `data: {id : id}` por `data: {'id' : id}`. Suponiendo que en id realmente tienes un valor.
El código jQuery debería quedar así:

```
$("button").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
          url: 'form.php',
          method: "POST",
          data: {'id' : id},
          success: function() {
            $("#form").load("form.php");
          }
        });
  });
```

Por otro lado deberías agregar una validación en tu código PHP para determinar si realmente estas recibiendo el valor antes de intentar mostrarlo. Para esto puedes usar la función [isset](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php). El código debería quedar así:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
   $id = $_POST['id'];
   echo $id;
}else{
   echo "No llegó el valor id";
 }
 ?>
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar mandando la data en una cadena de texto, algo así:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var cadena = "id=" + id;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'form.php',
      method: "POST",
      data: cadena,
      success: function() {
        $("#form").load("form.php");
      }
    });
```

});

Yo siempre he trabajado así y me funciona.